# Neo4j - Order by relevance

Tags: java, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, columnsorting

I'd like to order returned data by relevance in Neo4j.

For my purpose, relevance can be simplified to "Index of the word I'm searching for", where the lower index the higher relevance.

**Example**

I have these three nodes:

```
node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "Bearing replacement Skateboard"
    }
}

node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "Skateboard"
    }
}

node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "L7 Skateboard"
    }
}
```

I want them to be returned with this order:

```
node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "Skateboard" // name.indexOf("Skateboard") = 0
    }
}

node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "L7 Skateboard"  // name.indexOf("Skateboard") = 3
    }
}

node : {
    Label: PROD
    properties : {
        name: "Bearing replacement Skateboard"  // name.indexOf("Skateboard") = 19
    }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
String query = "MATCH (n:PROD) where LOWER(n.name) CONTAINS LOWER({textToSearch}) RETURN n ORDER BY LOWER(n.name) ASC LIMIT 15";

String textToSearch = "Skateboard";

Map<String, Object> queryParams = new HashMap<>();
queryParams.put("textToSearch", textToSearch);
try (
    Transaction ignored = database.beginTx();
    Result resultSet = database.execute(query, queryParams)
) {
    Iterator<Node> results = resultSet.columnAs("n");
    while (results.hasNext()) {
        Node node = results.next();
        /* data processing here */
    }
}
```

This just orders results by name ascendant. Is there a way to tell neo4j to sort based on `n.name.indexOf({textToFind})`?

Comment: You could always create a user-defined function which returns the indexOf() result using the Java string functions. Then you could just call your function and order by its value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about doing something like this in Cypher

```
MATCH (n:PROD) 
WHERE n.name_lc CONTAINS toLower({textToSearch})
WITH n, SPLIT(n.name_lc, toLower({textToSearch})) as parts
RETURN n.name, SIZE(parts[0]) AS leading
ORDER BY leading
```

To make effective use of the above...

Create an index on a lowercase version of the property

```
CREATE INDEX ON :PROD(name_lc)
```

Copy the regular name to a lowercase version

```
MATCH (n:PPOD)
SET n.name_lc = toLower(n.name)
```

Comment: What would I have to replace `WITH [...] as terms` with if I want to do the same thing on the selected nodes?

Comment: I updated the answer to remove the WITH... and add your MATCH statement.  I also added a little logic to handle the case where there is no matching word in the item name.

Comment: Hmm, it works but it's extremely slow... It takes 3 seconds for the first search, then 1 second for each subsequent search. Is there a way to make it faster?

Comment: So, there are a few things you can do to make it faster.  Since you are lowering the property when the CONTAINS is performed that will be very expensive. If you created a lowercase version of your name, indexed that and used it for comparisons everything will be a lot faster.  Also, because you are using contains, that CASE statement I added it completely redundant.

Comment: Adjusting the query to your latest update and creating the index did the trick. The query time is 10-50ms now. Thank you!